# Detecting HTML <a> click-to-call support in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, webkit, tel

There are two ways to have click-to-call links in HTML

- `<a href="wtai://wp/mc;+1800229933</a>` WTAI style (Nokia, others)
- `<a href="tel:+1-800-275-2273">Call Apple Customer Support at 1-800-275-2273</a>.` TEL style (Apple)

How one can

- detect which format is supported by current user agent in Javascript?
- Is it possible to do the detection without relying the user agent string

More info

- http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/click-to-call-links-mobile-browsers
- http://www.raizlabs.com/blog/2007/07/02/iphone-telephone-hyperlinks/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872090/how-to-check-if-a-custom-protocol-supported the accepted answer there might give you some good ideas as well. :)

Comment: there's also "callto:" which skype still uses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maximiliano Firtman has a great article on [how to create click-to-call links for mobile browsers](https://firt.dev/click-to-call). He states that the `tel:` protocol is supported by almost every mobile device, including: Safari on iOS, Android Browser, webOS Browser, Symbian browser, Internet Explorer, Opera Mini and low-end devices browsers.

Because of the wide support of the `tel:` protocol, I would suggest just use the `tel:` protocol. To support Nokia I would check if the [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent) contains Nokia footprint. If so, replace `tel:` to `wtai://wp/mc;`

If you can use jQuery, the Javascript could look something like:

```
if (/(Series60|Nokia)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
  $("a[href^='tel:']").each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace("tel:", "wtai://wp/mc;");
  });
}
```