# Is "Mumble" installed or not

Tags: php, checkout

I have a link that point on a "mumble url" like "mumble://mumble-4.verygames.n...".
When the user have mumble, the programm launch itself and request login and password to connect him to the server, and that's all I want. The problem is when the user doesn't have mumble installed,.. the url points nowhere and the user get an error page. How can I check if mumble is installed or not ?

I've tried the file_exists and some fopen php scripts but the fact is that I have no idea of how to check it.

Any idea, any answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if it is possible, you will need javascript to check it, not php.

Answer (score 0):

Mumble acts as a **custom protocol handler** on a user's system. PHP is not the way to find out if it is installed on a system. You need to keep in mind that PHP is a server side technology. `file_exists()` will always look at your server's hard drive.

Javascript would be the way to test something like this on the client side. Unfortunately, there is no easy, cross-browser way to do it. The following two Stackoverflow question explain this quite well:

- [How to check if a custom protocol supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872090/how-to-check-if-a-custom-protocol-supported)
- [How to detect browser's protocol handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers)

Looking around, there is an attempt at creating a cross-browser detection script, maybe it is worth a look for your purpose: http://www.rajeshsegu.com/2012/09/browser-detect-custom-protocols/