# Can javascript redirect my page to a url and if fails without alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a app link something like this,

```
pudding://anime/87667266347
```

I want a kind of javascript to try to redirect to this url. and if redirection fails, do nothing, without alert and just stay on current page.

```
try{
    window.location.href = "pudding://anime/87667266347";
}catch(error){
    //do nothing
}
```

The code above seems can not dismiss the browser alert popup.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `pudding://`? :D

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872090/how-to-check-if-a-custom-protocol-supported

Comment: 'browser alert popup' sounds like a security feature to prevent users from potentially dangerous auto-redirects. Are you trying to bypass client-side security features? (hint: this is bad)

Comment: You can do via ajax, but only for internal urls. If you want to ping external url then create a script or servlet on the server which does your job and sends the response to you, and use javascript to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer from this question [How to check if an app is installed from a web-page on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044805/how-to-check-if-an-app-is-installed-from-a-web-page-on-an-iphone)

```
$(function(){
        if (getQueryVariable("direct") == null) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = window.location.href + "?direct=no";
            }, 10);
            window.location = "pudding://anime/53b80d30abacae00038b4568";
        }
    });
    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split("&");
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
            if (pair[0] == variable) {
                return pair[1];
            }
        }
       return null;
    }
```