# Google Chrome : Check if particular app is installed on the system or not

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, ppapi

I'm working on a Quick Meeting type app. Where I want to check whether my app is installed on the system or not.

My Application installer copies the plugin to "Internet Plugins" folder on Mac OSX and ".mozila/plugins" on Linux.

I'm using this web plugin(NPAPI) to detect whether a application is installed on the system or not.

As we know, web plugins can access using `navigator.plugins`.

If plugin is found in plugins array then we were deciding to launch the application using custom url handler implemented by installed app, otherwise download the installer and ask user to install the app first.

This works fine with Firefox and Safari but not with Google Chrome. Also Chromium doesn't support NPAPI plugins and Google Chrome is dropping support for it.

I thought of using Pepper Plugin, but it doesn't have any api to check installed apps nor to access local files say in users home dir.

Any idea how to do it. Any pointer on this would be helpful.

Comment: One small correction: Chromium has exactly the same level of support for NPAPI that Google Chrome does (because it's the same codebase).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are registering a custom protocol already, this boils down to [detecting the presence of a protocol handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27489665/approaches-of-detection-of-custom-protocol-in-chrome-and-safari-browsers).

Comment: This plugin approach works great on Windows and Mac OSX, but fails in Linux OS like Ubuntu. On Ubuntu, Google Chrome failed to detect the plugin itself. navigator.plugins doesn't list our plugin.

Comment: I didn't suggest you use a plugin, I said you should look at the other question since any answer there would apply just as well to you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention one thing in my last comment. The other approach mentioned in the link provided by you i.e. launch application using custom protocol handler and detect application is installed or not. This approach also works great on windows and mac but not on Linux OS, like Ubuntu 14.04. 

Anyways thanks for reply, I would investigate around it.