# Check if a Registry Class exists by Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, registry, telegram

how to check if `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\tg` exists or not by Javascript (Supported by All Browsers).

Comment: Do you want to check it from web page? Or from program running locally on windows machine?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev from web page By javascript.

Comment: I don't think you can access any key in registry from web page javascript. Because it's security restriction. Registry can contain some sensitive information like login credentials.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev i found somethings but all of them are written with ActiveXObject() which are not supported by Chrome...

Comment: Right. ActiveXObject is windows specific feature is only supported in Internet Explorer. Also it's not longer supported in latest Microsoft browser - Edge. Bottom line: it's possible in some old browsers, but will not be supported at all in future.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev Is there a way to check if `tg://` protocol exists? it's related to Telegram app.

Comment: Looks like there is no universal way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2872090/93988

Comment: @IvanNevostruev anyways thanks for your help.