# Check if a browser supports a custom protocol using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows, custom-protocol

I have an application which needs to be installed on windows machine which uses a custom protocol like "myapp://". So i have a button on a web page which when clicked opens that application. 
When i click the button, i need to check whether that protocol is supported by the browser or not, if yes, open the application, if no, show an error.
There are several hacks available on the internet and I tried a few but didn't seem to work. I want to do this in a cleaner way. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

No can do. The browser is specifically blocked from that level of access. You can't even read a file directly from their system unless the user gives it to you via a `file` input.

In theory, you could write your application in such a way that it reports back to your server when it's installed but that doesn't guarantee that it was installed on *that* machine.

Comment: okay. Is it possible to check whether a custom-protocol is supported by the user's machine?

Comment: @RevantChandanala The simple answer is "no." The more accurate answer is "it depends and even if it is possible, [it's a pain to get to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872090/how-to-check-if-a-custom-protocol-supported)."