# Call phonenumber on button click on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a responsive django app that shows a phone number on a button click. I'd like to trigger the phone call on mobile devices. How do I detect the device such that the call to phone action only happens on mobile devices, but on desktop it only shows text? I've seen this post [How to trigger a phone call when clicking a link in a web page on mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone) but it doesn't help much.

```
 <input onclick="change()"  class="btn btn-primary phone" type="button" value="Show Phone Number" id="myButton1" />

      <script type="text/javascript">
      function change() 
      {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
        elem.value = "" + {{contact_no}};

      }
      </script>
```

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) might help.

Comment: Did you search around? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345177/use-jquery-to-detect-whether-a-device-can-make-telephone-calls-supports-tel

Comment: Have you tried using a `callto://` [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)? I'm not sure its a global standard (as it seems to be a Skype-centric spec, but it might be something that mobile phone browsers handle well.

Comment: What is wrong with displaying a phone link to all people? People use their (desktop) computers to make calls all the time. Do you know Skype? Just use `<a href='tel:+1123456789'>` and stop creating hurdles.

Comment: @allcaps my target audience doesn't use Skype to make calls on their computers! I just need the call to phone action happen only on phones and show simple number text on computers.

Comment: Have you looked at this `<a href="tel:+1800229933">Call us free!</a>`

Answer (score 1):

use following

```
< a href='tel:+9190123456' >
```

But before using this you must be use a condition for mobile device and computer to trigger call with number as computer does not support any call feature .