# check if tel URI linked

Tags: php, javascript, uri, tel

Is there a way to find out if the tel URI is linked in the browser? Usually the visitor would get an error message and I would like to avoid it. It does not matter if it is done via JS or PHP.

Thank you.

Comment: yo need to describe more detailed what the problem is and what you want to do.

Comment: it's not really a problem but it does not look good. Create a tel link and click it. As long as it is not linked you will get an error that the browser does not know what to do with "tel". And I would not create the link if it is not possible to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect browser's protocol handlers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers)

Comment: Only thing is, if there is support for `tel://` then the ability will be lost. My work computer has Microsoft Lync which handles it, and I'm not sure there would be any way to detect support for it...most likely