# Codeigniter base_url() added for every <a> tag

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url, tel

I am currently developing a project with CI. In the project I need to add "tel" in "a" tag for calling from the website. 
I addded like this
`<a link="tel:+919898989898">`
But when I open link from page, the link is like this `abc.com/tel:+919898989898` and it is redirecting to a error page.If I manually remove the baseurl from the page it is working.
Please give me some idea why it is happening and how to prevent the baseurl adding auomatically.
Please don't give link which explain the "tel" tag description

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088523/click-to-call-html

Comment: don't you mean `<a href="..."></a>` instead of `<a link="...">` or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: I always just do `<a href="tel:555-666-77777">555-666-77777</a>` for phones.  Similar to `<a href="mailto:...">` ... for email. You could try `<a href="cell:...">` if it's a cell phone though :o)>

Comment: It is a typo. sorry for that. I used <a link="tel:+919898989898"></a>

Comment: have a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone

Comment: My main problem is, it is adding baseurl with "a" tag automatically. From page the link is like that "abc.com/tel:+919898989898". If I manually remove the baseurl from the page it is working. please give me  a solution which prevent the baseurl adding auomatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>.`

Comment: i  think `<a href="tel:555-666-77777">555-666-77777</a>` is better like I said in the comments, :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="tel:1111-2222-33"><img src="path/to/phone/icon.jpg" /></a>
```