# Why does my phone number href link redirect to 'About:Blank' address and how do I fix the issues?

Tags: html, css, action

```html
<p>
  <a href="callto://4407398169667">+44 (073) 981-69667</a>
  <span>
    <a href="mailto:admin@indelibleelevations.com?Subject=Quick%20query" target="_top">admin@indelibleelevations.com</a>
  </span>
</p>
```

Above is the format I am using to direct service users to either call me or email me. However, the number keeps directing me to a blank page with 'About:Blank' written in the address bar and the email goes to a blue screen with 'mailto:admin@indelibleelevations.com?Subject=Quick%20query' written in the address bar. I really cant see where I have gone wrong. Is anyone able to see an error or know what the error could be?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: It may help to read this, on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click to call html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088523/click-to-call-html)

Answer (score 0):

Your link code for the phone number is `href="//4407398169667"`. You have to use `tel` in there: `href="tel://4407398169667"`

Comment: why the double slash?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this what are you looking to do.

```
  <style type="text/css">
li {
    display: inline;
}
li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover {
    color: #2196F3;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

Html Code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="tel:44-073-981-69667">+44 (073) 981-69667</a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto:example@email.com">admin@indelibleelevations.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="/js/default.asp" target="_blank">You can put some text here</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image]