# Detecting Custom Protocol Handler in Windows 8+ with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-8, protocols, custom-protocol

I am trying to detect if my application to handle a custom protocol is installed and working using the different browsers.  I have looked at other questions on this site such as:
[How to detect browser's protocol handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/836777/3275846),
and have looked at resources like this to make it work on most platforms in most browsers.

Before you flag this as duplicate, hear me out...

I was able to get my function working on everything except Chrome on Windows 8+.  I cannot use the window focus method on Chrome like I can on Windows 7 because it pops up the message that asks me to find an app in the store.

**Is there any way (short of an extension) to detect a custom protocol handler in Windows 8+ on Chrome?**

UPDATE:

Using an onBlur to detect it only works on Windows 7, because in 8+, if it doesn't find something to open your protocol, it opens the 'find something from the app store' dialog that makes the browser lose focus.

Comment: chrome on windows is important, which prototcol do you need to detect?

Comment: @dandavis I agree.  It is a custom protocol... for example  "foo://"

Comment: @dandavis It doesn't have a mime type.  As far as the name goes, it could be whatever I wanted it to be.

Comment: you might be able to sniff the side-effect from a popup window's behavior, like if it closed right away or stayed stalled on the google plug (i don't know, it just sounds reasonable)

Comment: what do you expect it to do ? ignore your protcol ? please clarify the problem and the expected solution.

Comment: @ProllyGeek "I am trying to detect if my application to handle a custom protocol is installed and working using the different browsers." - What I expect it to do; "I was able to get my function working on everything except Chrome on Windows 8+."- The problem; "Is there any way...to detect a custom protocol handler in Windows 8+ on Chrome?"-The expected solution.  What more do you need?

Comment: Hi PixelAcorn, I am in the same problem on Chrome. Have you solved it and if yes, could you tell me how you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I think you were on the right track. It is definitly not that easy but chrome so far was not my problem, more like Edge + IE but my solution is assuming they don't support the protocol if anything fails or they don't respond correctly which they do sometimes.

The blur/focus is something to check but you need to check it in combination with a visibility change. The HTML5 Visiblity API and this post [about it](http://greensock.com/forums/topic/9059-cross-browser-to-detect-tab-or-window-is-active-so-animations-stay-in-sync-using-html5-visibility-api/) helped me figure out a solution that is pretty solid except the mentioned browsers above because they have some issues with the *navigator.msLaunchUri* function and have their own approach implemented which doesn't rely on blur/focus. But the function is bugged and doesn't respond correctly all the time.

You can find my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYYKVE?editors=1010). Hopefully that helps you even though it is a bit late for an answer. This works for mobile browsers as well but I didn't test multiple yet worked for my Android 6.0.2. Might need some tweaks in the long run but I think it is pretty solid.

```
(function() {
  var noProtocolHash = '#protocolXYnotsupported',
      checkDelay = 800, // apps might start slowly
      isBlurred = false,
      inCheck = false,
      inLauncherCheck = false,

  tabVisible = (function(){ 
      var stateKey, 
          eventKey, 
          keys = {
                  hidden: "visibilitychange",
                  webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
                  mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
                  msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
      };
      for (stateKey in keys) {
          if (stateKey in document) {
              eventKey = keys[stateKey];
              break;
          }
      }
      return function(c) {
          if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
          return !document[stateKey];
      }
  })(),

  isMSIE = function(){
    var rv = -1;

    if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
      var ua = navigator.userAgent;
      var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
      if(re.exec(ua) != null){
        rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
      }
    }
    else if(navigator.appName == 'Netscape'){
      var ua = navigator.userAgent;
      var re  = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
      if(re.exec(ua) != null){
        rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
      }
    }
    return (rv !== -1)? true: false;
  },

  isEdge = function(){
    return window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
  },

  checkIfFocusLost = function($el){
    try {
      document.location.href = $el.attr("href");
    } catch (ex) {
        document.location.href = document.location.href + '/' + noProtocolHash;
    }

    setTimeout(checkVisibility, checkDelay);
  },

  checkVisibility = function(){
    if(tabVisible() && !isBlurred){
      handleNoProtocol();
    }
    else {
      handleProtocol();
    }
  },

  handleNoProtocol = function(){
    $('.result').text('has no protocol');

    inLauncherCheck = false;
  },

  handleProtocol = function(){
    $('.result').text('has the protocol');

    inLauncherCheck = false;
  },

  checkHash = function(){
    if(document.location.hash === noProtocolHash){
      handleNoProtocol();
    }
  },

  checkLauncherProtocol = function($el){
    inLauncherCheck = true;

    navigator.msLaunchUri($el.attr("href"), function(){
      handleProtocol();
    }, 
    function(){
      handleNoProtocol();
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
      // fallback when edge is not responding correctly
      if(inLauncherCheck === true){
        handleNoProtocol();
      }
    }, 500);
  },

  checkIfHasProtocol = function($el){
    inCheck = true;

    if(isEdge() || isMSIE()){
      checkLauncherProtocol($el);
    }
    else {
      checkIfFocusLost($el)
    }
  };

  checkHash();
  tabVisible(function(){
    if(tabVisible() && inCheck){
      handleProtocol();
      inCheck = false;
    }    
  });

  window.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    isBlurred = true;   
  });

  window.addEventListener("focus", function(){
    isBlurred = false; 
    inCheck = false;
  });

  window.checkIfHasProtocol = checkIfHasProtocol;
})();

$('.protocol').click(function(e) {
  checkIfHasProtocol($(this));
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

My code is tested with Win10: Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Edge + Android: Chrome (6.0.1)

there is also this github project https://github.com/ismailhabib/custom-protocol-detection which sorta has a similar approach maybe a little bit more maintained but i couldn't get their solution working for some reasons but maybe this is exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help you [here](https://gist.github.com/keyvanfatehi/f2f521c654bab106fdf9) with different browsers, but please define you question better or add at least some kinda example to make it clear.

Comment: I've looked at solutions like that. The problem is that that Chrome solution only works on Windows 7. I don't quite see how my question isn't clear....

Comment: Hi PixelAcorn, I am in the same problem on Chrome and waiting your feedback