# Custom protocol detection across browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, uri, protocols

How to check from browser  whether the desktop app is installed or not, as if not installed user will be shown a installer link and  if not we would just start the desktop app, the challenge here we are using custom protocol handler concept to detect whether the custom url is registered, but this only works in firefox and ie11 on win8.

On chrome there is no way to detect the proptocl handler being present, based on blurring of window will not work incase user checks the donot show window option, then the custom url alert will not be shown and there is no way to know the custom url is registered. Same behaviour goes for ie11 on win7.
could anyone help here

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect browser's protocol handlers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108347/detecting-custom-protocol-handler-in-windows-8-with-chrome

Comment: Hi Som, I am in the same problem on Chrome. Have you solved it and if yes, could you tell me how you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, but never used up to now, this:

https://github.com/ismailhabib/custom-protocol-detection

> Custom Protocol Detection in Browser
>
> Detect whether a custom protocol is available in browser (FF, Chrome,
>   IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11, and Edge)
>
> The implementation is different from one browser to another, sometimes
>   depend on which OS you are. Most of them are hacks, meaning that the
>   solution is not the prettiest.

Comment: For the future reader, this project is no longer maintained and will fail in several cases