# Is there any way to detect user installed telegram app on window/ios/android?

Tags: telegram

I'm now finding how to detect user has telegram apps on there OS. When your browser and click some telegram bot's link, then they send popup "do you want to open with telegram app?". but when you don't have telegram apps on your PC, they didn't send any popups. I wan't to know how this is possible and that can i detect that situation for my own program.

Comment: perhaps they have a url handler like `telegram://`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect browser's protocol handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and it helped me a lot. But the answer's limit is when you have custom protocol in clients registry, then it just execute the URI and open the telegram app. and I wan't just detect it is there or not. I'm curious about just check exsists of a app and client don't know about what happens