# How can I register a domain protocol for my application in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, deep-linking

In Windows, I wanted to register my domain protocol (https link) for my C++ application. I was able to achieve the same for a custom URL as said over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38205984/14467573). For custom protocol, some changes in the registry helped me in achieving that.

Goal: let's say if the application is installed it should open my app by some prompt box in browser is also fine else it should open the website on the browser.

How can I resolve this?

### Edit

Giving an example, let's say we create a teams meeting. We get a teams meeting link in our outlook mail. Right? It is an https link. If we click on the link that prompts in the browser that this wants to open teams and if accept that it launches Teams application. Wanted to have something similar behaviour...

Now the browser prompts to launch the correct application in the open button Right? So, it is also handling the "https://teams.microsoft.com"

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a security nightmare. I can just see all those "helpful" applications grabbing https://google.com etc for themselves.

Comment: Giving an example, Let's say we create a teams meeting. We get a teams meeting link in our outlook mail. Right? It is an https link.  If we click on the link that prompts in the browser that this wants to open teams and if accept that it launches Teams application.  

Wanted to have something similar behaviour...

Comment: @RohanPande That behavior is simply the result of a custom URL scheme, as described in the question you linked to. It does not involve registering the domain as special. The fact that Microsoft Teams didn't manage to register a domain to a particular app should indicate that it's not possible/practical to do so.

Comment: @Sneftel I have updated the question with image. It might help what I am trying to say.

Comment: In that image, the "link of this type" your browser is asking about is a link starting with `msteams:`. You went to a website, and that website has a script which redirects you to `msteams:foo`, the browser asked you if it was okay to open the application which is registered to be used for `msteams:` URLs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect browser's protocol handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers)

Comment: @Sneftel When I was trying the same for custom url which I shared in the question after making those changes in the Registry. So, then browser started to handle for the custom url. Right? So instead of custom url I am asking how can I do the same for https url??